# In WPF I can't see whats wrong with my C# Storyboard and DoubleAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, scaling

Im attempting to create a storyboard in C# not XAML to control scaling of an image, so i can easily alter the `ScaleTransform.ScaleX` and `ScaleTransform.ScaleY` values in a `DoubleAnimation`.

So far I believe i have created the animations and added it to a new storyboard, and the appropriate values change in the C# when i check with breakpoints, but it's not actually working.

My C# looks like this:

```
    public void SetStatistics(double[] value)
    {
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        //Wedge Animation X-Axis    
        DoubleAnimation wax = new DoubleAnimation();
        //Wedge Animation Y-Axis  
        DoubleAnimation way = new DoubleAnimation();

        ScaleTransform st = ((ScaleTransform)FindName("wedge1scale"));

        wax = new DoubleAnimation();
        way = new DoubleAnimation();
        wax.Duration = sb.Duration;
        way.Duration = sb.Duration;

        sb.Children.Add(wax);
        sb.Children.Add(way);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(wax, new PropertyPath("(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));

        //End scale from calculation with an Enum value
        wax.To = StatMin + (StatPercent * value[1]);
        //Start scale from current value
        wax.From = st.ScaleX;

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(way, new PropertyPath("(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"));

        //End scale from calculation with an Enum value
        way.To = StatMin + (StatPercent * value[1]);
        //Start scale from current value
        way.From = st.ScaleY;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(wax, Wedge1);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(way, Wedge1);

        Main.Resources.Add("animation", sb);

        sb.Begin();
    }
```

My XAML Image is like this:

```
    <Image x:Name="Wedge1" Source="Images/Wedge.png" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.008,1.027" Height="682" Width="263" Canvas.Left="869.04" Canvas.Top="-158.251" >

        <Image.RenderTransform>
              <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="wedge1scale" ScaleX="0.555" ScaleY="0.555"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="88.102" Y="-4.381"/>
              </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

Thanks in advance for any info :)

Comment: `Im attempting to create a storyboard in C#` - Why are you doing that? That's what XAML is for, y'know...

Comment: I have found that when i create the usual xaml storyboard and double animation, i cant easily access the children of children, this way seemed like a logically more accessible way therefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `PropertyPath`. You would have to write `RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX` and `RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleY` in order to animate the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of the first child of the TransformGroup in the Image's `RenderTransform`.

```
var wax = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
var way = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

wax.To = ...
way.To = ...

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
    wax, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX"));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
    way, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleY"));

Storyboard.SetTarget(wax, Wedge1);
Storyboard.SetTarget(way, Wedge1);

var sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(wax);
sb.Children.Add(way);
sb.Begin();
```

---

And it would be less code without the Storyboard:

```
var wax = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
var way = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

wax.To = ...
way.To = ...

wedge1scale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, wax);
wedge1scale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, way);
```

---

And I guess in your case it isn't necessary to set the `From` property, as the animations start from the current property values by default.

Comment: Thanks i will try this. Yes i did think that the from would not be necessary, it was something i added later on when trying to find the issue.

Comment: Also when i get this working i will have to apply it to 15 other images simultaneously, so i may need a storyboard?

Comment: Yeah that did the trick thanks Clemens. I just couldn't see it :P